# cannot install both kubelet-1.18.4-0.x86_64 and kubelet-1.21.3-0.x86_64

Tags: kubernetes, centos8

```
[root@centos1 ~]# yum -y update
Ultima verifica della scadenza dei metadati: 8:14:04 fa il dom 01 ago 2021 19:20:32 EDT.
Errore:
 Problema: cannot install both kubelet-1.18.4-0.x86_64 and kubelet-1.21.3-0.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package kubernetes-cni-0.8.7-0.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package kubelet-1.21.3-0.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [common problem](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/92463) there is either a bug in yum/dnf, or a bug in how Kubernetes repository is set up.

One workaround is to mask unneeded versions of kubelet. E.g. here's my `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
[main]
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
best=True
skip_if_unavailable=False
exclude = kubelet-1.18.* kubelet-1.17.* kubelet-1.16.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have conflicting packages, you should use `--allowerasing` to allow dnf to resolve the conflict.

```
dnf --allowerasing update
```

Don't use `-y` here; you want to inspect the output to ensure that it makes sense before installing.